# Error propagation in cone width for kinematic neutron imaging

Tags: calculus, error-propagation

I'm trying to figure out the error in the opening angle for a cone created with kinematic neutron imaging. The angle is defined as:

$$\theta = \sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{Ep}{E}}$$

And I want to find the error in this angle. I don't know how to propagate error through an inverse sine function so I made a substitution where:
$$
    u = \sin^2(\theta) \\
    u = \frac{Ep}{E}
$$
My work is attached, but my delta-theta at the end doesn't have units of radians or degrees. Where did I go wrong? Here is a LaTex file showing my entire process. [image: work]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. If you still have access to the source of the work you have linked, kindly copy it into the body of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem being $$\theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{Ep}{E}}\right)$$ let us start with
$$\theta = \sin^{-1}(X) \qquad \text{where} \qquad X=\sqrt{\frac{Ep}{E}}$$ Using derivatives
$$\Delta \theta=\frac{\Delta X}{\sqrt{1-X^2}}$$
Now
$$X=\sqrt{\frac{Ep}{E}}\implies \log(X)=\frac 12 \log(Ep)-\frac 12 \log(E)$$ Using again derivatives, then 
$$\frac{\Delta X} X=\frac 12 \frac{\Delta Ep}{Ep}+\frac 12 \frac{\Delta E}{E}\implies \Delta X=??? \implies \Delta \theta=???$$